How to manage race conditions with Data Validation in a 3-Tier architecture Web API
My web api has 3 layers: Controller, Service Layer, and Repository. This is accessed via a SPA.
Imagine the scenario where you have a form in the SPA that takes the First Name and Last Name and sends to the API to create a user. In this scenario you know 100 percent two people cannot have the same First and Last name.
I have setup a data annotation that queries the DB to see if that First Name and Last Name combination exists and if it does it rejects it but if it doesnt exists the procedure to the controller action begins with binding these variables to a model. This then moves to the service layer and finally to the repository layer which will add the first name and last name and create the user.
However, there could be a race condition that occurs using data annotation for validation of this type so I am unsure how to handle this.
One idea is our database can return an error if this were to occur and I could try and catch this but my repository assumes returning a POCO with the newly created user so not sure what object to return down the line from the service layer to the controller layer and back to the frontend to show there is an error.

"what object to return down the line from the service layer to the controller layer and back to the frontend to show there is an error" - Throw an exception?

When you throw an exception does it basically break the chain and go right to returning the response to the frontend?

Throwing an exception exits the method and returns control up the calling stack to either wherever the exception is caught or to the top of the stack.  Anywhere along the stack you can catch and handle the exception.

Is there an exception you could post as an answer that is most appropriate for a web api response?

Well, you wouldn't want the API to have an unhandled exception.  Basically wherever you find that the data can't be saved because it already exists, you can throw a custom exception there.  Further up the stack, likely in the API layer, you can catch that exception and return a meaningful response to the client indicating the problem.  (Maybe they need to refresh their data to get the latest and submit an update operation instead of a create operation, maybe they can't proceed and need to check with someone else, etc.)

I would argue against throwing an exception in this scenario. Exceptions should be for exceptional circumstances where the program flow simply cannot continue which is not the case here. Exceptions also incur a lot of overhead due to all the additional information they marshal. Instead consider the Result Pattern. Side note, why are you enforcing uniqnueness on firstname & lastname. It's perfectly feasible more than one person could have the same combination.
